# How does the `key` arg in Python bisect work?

Tags: python, key, python-3.10, bisect

I believe I understand sorting and bisection. When using `key` with `sorted` I get the results I expect, but when I call `bisect(..., key=fn)` I don't understand the outcome. Possibly a bug? Where would I report that?

```
from bisect import bisect

fn = lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1] % 2, tup[1])

lst = [('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
x = ('a', 3)

print(sorted(lst, key=fn))        # [('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
print(sorted(lst + [x], key=fn))  # [('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 3), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
# so `x` sorts into position 2.

lst.sort(key=fn)
print(bisect(lst, x, key=fn))     # 3 (!)

lst_fn = sorted([fn(item) for item in lst])
print(bisect(lst_fn, fn(x)))      # 2
```

I don't understand why `x` would sort to position 3. Am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bisect` expects the lookup value `x` to already have `key` applied. So this works:

```
print(bisect(lst, fn(x), key=fn))  # 2
```

I think this is very counter-intuitive. After all, we're looking for a place to insert `x`, not `fn(x)`.

Comment: I found that counter-intuitive as well until I read the discussion in the bug report linked by Thomas' answer, which contains among other "it was decided this way because this is slightly more general (you can apply the function when you need to apply the function, but sometimes you only have a key)" and some examples.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91966

The issue has been reported.
Hopefully, the documentation will be updated soon.